# Cформировать верный массив по вложениям

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите, как получить количество повторений из подмассива? [Входные данные](http://joxi.ru/p270zE1cWK6V4A):

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'URL' => 'http://www.transsunline.ru/',
    'WORLD' => 
    array (
      '200кг' => '200кг',
      'ТрансСанЛайн' => 'Транс Онлайн',
    ),
    'ERROR' => 2,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'URL' => 'http://www.transsunline.ru/vopros-otvet',
    'WORLD' => 
    array (
      'mdash' => 'dash',
      'ТрансСанЛайн' => 'Транс Онлайн',
    ),
    'ERROR' => 5,
  ),
)
```

Нужно получить массив вида:

```
array (
  '200кг' => 
  array (
    0 => 'http://www.transsunline.ru/',
  ),
  'ТрансСанЛайн' => 
  array (
    0 => 'http://www.transsunline.ru/',
    1 => 'http://www.transsunline.ru/vopros-otvet',
  ),
  'mdash' => 
  array (
    0 => 'http://www.transsunline.ru/vopros-otvet',
  ),
)
```

Получается нужно получить список упоминаний ошибок слов и страниц на которых они расположены. Пробовал делать слово ключом и добавлять в него, но ничего не выходит, так как URL заносятся неверно. Как можно реализовать?

Comment: если ответ вам помог, то примите его нажав зеленую галочку слева. спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$array = [
    [
        'URL' =>  'http://www.transsunline.ru/',
        'WORLD' => [
            '200кг' => '200 кг',
            'ТрансСанЛайн' => 'Транс Онлайн'
        ],
        'ERROR' => 2
    ],
    [
        'URL' => 'http://www.transsunline.ru/vopros-otvet',
        'WORLD' => [
            'mdash' => 'dash',
            'ТрансСанЛайн' => 'Транс Онлайн'
        ],
        'ERROR' => 5
    ]
];

foreach ($array as $_key => $_value)
{
    foreach (array_keys($_value['WORLD']) as $k => $v)
    {
        $res[$v][] = $_value['URL'];
    }
}

print_r($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/n3mpX

Comment: Красота. ☝ не стану свой вариант размещать )))

Comment: Только можно foreach без ключей использовать. Они тут не нужны.

Comment: Спасибо большое) Это лучшее решение, что могло быть